# Kак решить задачу пользователь начинает скролить перенести его во вторую секцию http://genrich.ru/holmhill2/ ,как это првильно сделать?

Tags: javascript, jquery

как решить задачу года пользователь начинает скролить пренести его во вторую секцию http://genrich.ru/holmhill2/ ,тут с костылями ,как это првильно сделать ?
Тут задача втом чтоб каждый раз когда пользователь начинает скролить в первой его переносило во вторую секцию ,а когда во второй скролит в первую

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).one('scroll', (event) => {
  let top = $('#anchor2').first().offset().top;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: top }, 800);
})
```

Comment: Тут задача втом чтоб каждый раз когда пользователь начинает скролить его переносило во вторую секцию ,а когда во второй скролит в первую

Comment: В таком случае нужно обернуть данный ответ в функцию с параметром анкора, определить направление скролла delta = parseInt(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail); и после перемещения в зависимости от направления скролла вызывать функцию с нужным анкором.